# Semantic URL with .htaccess (Error 500)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to semantic my website URL, but when I want to show result I have a 500 Error

```html
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80
```

The .htaccess code

```html
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} 10/
RewriteRule 10/ http://localhost/Cnxkhamsat/admin/edit.php?chi_id=10
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code appears to work fine when trying on a local machine, meaning there are no syntax errors.

The most likely scenario is that you do not have the appropriate permissions to use the `RewriteEngine`. This usually happens when using a shared hosting, or sometimes VPS.

If you have access to your `httpd.conf` file you can most likely turn the RewriteEngine on from there. If you don't have access to it, then you'll likely need to contact your hosting provider and tell them that you need them to allow you to use the rewrite engine.

Comment: Then take a look at your httpd.conf file. You may need to enable mod_rewrites. https://gist.github.com/jitendravyas/6002804 (take a look at line 149), you'll probably need to uncomment that

Comment: I open my httpd.conf, I delete this line `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` but no change :'(

Comment: delete? i said uncomment the line

Comment: How to uncomment the line ?

Comment: i don't want to be rude, but if you don't know how to uncomment a line of code, then I would strongly recommend against editing the httpd.conf file